# Unable to parse Ionic Config file. Please make sure it is valid JSON

Tags: ionic-framework

All of a sudden, I'm getting this while trying to run ionic. What's wrong?

```
C:\Users>ionic
Unable to parse Ionic Config file. Please make sure it is valid JSON (.ionic/ionic.config)

Caught exception:
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.module.exports.load (C:\Users\BBytes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\config.js:14:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BBytes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\utils\stats.js:31:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BBytes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\cli.js:3:18)

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues
```

Comment: Similar error here : Caught exception:
 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Answer (score 8):

I've found the source of the problem! My `C:/Users/{username}/.ionic/ionic.config` file was corrupted when my pc crashed /or due to some other error.

Weird that that file NEVER gets cleared when uninstalling ionic.

Just Delete the file and when you run `ionic serve` it will create the file by default in the folder.

Answer (score 7):

In `node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/config.js`

change

```
CONFIG_FILE: '.ionic/ionic.config',
```

to have a slash after the dot

```
CONFIG_FILE: './ionic/ionic.config'
```

Comment: i am not having ionic-app-lib folder in my node_modules. ionic info also fialing with same error

Answer (score 3):

Goto this path- `C:/Users/{username}/.ionic`
find file (`ionic.config`) and delete that file.

Answer (score 3):

In my case none of these solutions worked, I even tried uninstalling Ionic and cordova, and clearing the NPM cache.

**EDIT**

I finally figured out what was going on. Ionic is too stupid to handle the BOM (Byte Order Marker)  so to fix this, go to the file or files you're having trouble with.

1. click file save as
2. In the save dialog, click the arrow drop down next to the save button
3. Click Save With Encodings
4. Select yes you want to replace your file
5. An advanced options menu will pop up
6. Select UTF-8 without encodings, (scroll down they may not be in order)

**WORK-AROUND**

The way I solved this is by going to my current directory in command prompt,

> C:/MyProject

Then created a new Ionic Project with the same name as my current project,

```
ionic start MyProject
```

and then I selected the blank options,  this will create a sub directory in your project with blank configuration files.

Then just copy the `ionic.config.json` and the `tsconfig.json` back to the main repository.

After Do a Diff to make sure that you haven't lost any of the options you previously had.  I think in my case this was related to line ending, but that is just a guess because I never figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

go to

C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\config.js
and change

```
CONFIG_FILE: '.ionic/ionic.config'
```

to

```
CONFIG_FILE: './ionic/ionic.config'
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved very simply.

Just changed unicode of `ionic.config.json` to `UTF-8` (whitout suffix like -BOM)

You can use [notepad++](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwib4Jm4ytbVAhWDJ5oKHWpgC1sQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnotepad-plus-plus.org%2Fdownload%2F&usg=AFQjCNFCBJqyIc2YisTG74LS2eSZnUZ2Og) to do it very simply.

> The `ionic.config.json` file is located in your project's root.

It works like a charm now.