# ionic.config.json syntax error at position 0

Tags: ionic2, syntax-error

I'm trying to execute google maps web api for my ionic 2 project. 
After adding a proxy (For the browser CORS issue) and executing ionic serve, the following error is returned.

```
    Uh oh! There's a syntax error in your ionic.config.json file:
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0 
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.load (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\project.js:48:17)
    at Object.runr (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\cli.js:156:32)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\cli.js:54:9
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
```

The following is my ionic.config.json file:

```
    {
      "name": "NW",
      "app_id": "",
      "v2": true,
      "typescript": true,
      "proxies": [
        {
          "path": "/proxy",
          "proxyUrl": "https://maps.googleapis.com/"
        }
      ]
    }
```

My System Information is as below:

```
    Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
    Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
    Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
    Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
    Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
    ios-deploy version: Not installed
    ios-sim version: Not installed
    OS: Windows 10
    Node Version: v6.9.5
    Xcode version: Not installed
```

I tried to fix this by checking for foreign tokens and using a newly generated default ionic.config.json but same error persists.

Appreciate any ideas or solutions to this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello Foo Bar, I tried as you suggested and the same error is returned. I've updated the full console response above in my question.

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1952 uh oh

Comment: @suraj It doesn´t say it has a bad ending, in fact, thats a proper json for ionic.config, so problem must be other place...ionic things.

Comment: yes.. the json is not malformed as far as I can see

Comment: Hello, I tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776922/unable-to-parse-ionic-config-file-please-make-sure-it-is-valid-json) but unfortunately, it did not help. Currently trying to re-install the framework.

Comment: Hey, just found this: 
You have to set proxies in ionic.config.js, i.e:
module.exports = {
proxies: [{
"path": "/twitter/",
"proxyUrl": "https://api.twitter.com/"
}],
}

[FOUNDED HERE](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/proxy-problems-with-ionic-2/43354/5)

Answer (score 0):

Open your config file in Notepad++ and check the encoding format. The encoding format should be UTF-8 and nothing else, not even UTF-8 BOM. If it is, change it to UTF-8. save file and try running it again. Hope it helps.

Note: DO NOT USE Notepad to do the above steps, as notepad considers UTF_8 and UTF-8-BOM as same.