# The config file (.\ionic.config.json) is not valid JSON format

Tags: json, windows, cordova, ionic-framework

Every time I run this command: **ionic cordova build android --release**

I am using **cordova -v** 
7.0.1

I get this error:

```
The config file (.\ionic.config.json) is not valid JSON format.

Please fix any JSON errors in the file.
```

Here is my file:

```
{
  "app_id": "12345",
  "name": "myApp",
  "type": "ionic1"
}
```

I'm not sure what's going on here.

This command works fine: **cordova build android --release**

I am not sure what's going on with ionic.

Comment: check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776922/unable-to-parse-ionic-config-file-please-make-sure-it-is-valid-json helps

Comment: I tried that one and it had no effect.

Comment: May i ask why you are using (ionic cordova)  ?

Answer (score 14):

Goto this path- `C:/Users/{your_username}/.ionic`
find file `ionic.config` and delete it.

It will be auto-regenerated by the CLI.

Comment: It works for me. the file was a binary one. I delete it

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't my ionic config file after all. It was a package.json and bower.json files. They did not have the dependencies correctly in place and the app name was in uppercase. After I fixed my dependencies, I got the command to work.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

Remove .ionic from user home folder

```
rm -Rf ~/.ionic
```

Then, reinstall ionic:

```
npm i -g ionic
```

Answer (score 0):

just open the config.json file on your ide, delete all the content and ionic serve