# The file ionic.config.json is not a valid format

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I keep getting this weird error:

> The config file (.\ionic.config.json) is not a valid format

I've looked at a few questions answering this and they've told me to delete a file in:

> C:\Users\{user}\.ionic\ionic.config

but even if I do that the error are the same, which makes me think it's my local config file, which looks like this:

```
{
  "app_id": "",
  "name": "AstootClient",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "typescript": true,
  "v2": true
}
```

What can I do to make Ionic2 start working agian?

Comment: Try removing the `type` key. If that doesn't work I would suggest starting a new Ionic 2 project and compare your `ionic.config.json` with the new one.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already

Comment: Is this all ionic.config.json file content?

Comment: Yeah that's everything, I tried to see if it was the line endings as well but that didn't seem to work either @vega

Comment: I guess you should examine every line if it's correct, like the name is correctly spelled, etc...

Comment: What happens if you just keep the `app_id`, `name` and `type` keys? I've checked on some local projects and those are the only keys I have in that file...

Comment: @sebaferreras I've tried that as well nothing worked, I had to create a new project and copy the files over to get this working.  I think this was caused by inconsistent line endings, because that was the only difference I saw

Comment: I've posted a work around answer on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45391715/1938988) but I would really like to know what is actually causing this, I've had this problem several times already but usually it just goes away after playing with the file a bit